# Using radiobuttons in spinner with Java

Tags: java, android, spinner

I'm trying to add some radiobuttons in a spinner. However I want to do this by using only java. I've seen a lot of examples showing how to do it with xml resource but nothing like this. Ones getting resource from an array didn't work for me for some reason.  Here's my code

```
            spinnerrg = new Spinner(con);
            NodeList rl = child.getChildNodes();
            String[] radioadapt = new String[rl.getLength()];
            for(int j=1;j<rl.getLength();j++) {
                Element[] dumrad = new Element[rl.getLength()];
                Node dum = rl.item(j);
                if(dum instanceof Element) {
                    dumrad[j] = (Element) dum;
                    radioadapt[j] = dumrad[j].getAttribute("value");
                }
            }
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(con, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, radioadapt);
            spinnerrg.setAdapter(adapter);
            TextView radioText = new TextView(con);
            radioText.setText(child.getAttribute("label"));
            spinnerrg.setTag(child.getAttribute("id"));
            contList.add(radioText);
            contList.add(spinnerrg);
```

That nodeList is there because I'm parsing an xml file. for-loop works perfectly if I simply use radiogroup but can't manage to do it with spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this

```
spinnerrg = new Spinner(con);
            //RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(con);
            NodeList rl = child.getChildNodes();
            Vector<String> radioadapt = new Vector<String>();
            for(int j=0;j<rl.getLength();j++) {
                Element[] dumrad = new Element[rl.getLength()];
                Node dum = rl.item(j);
                if(dum instanceof Element) {
                    //RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(con);
                    dumrad[j] = (Element) dum;
                    //rb.setHint(dumrad[j].getAttribute("value"));
                    radioadapt.add(dumrad[j].getAttribute("value"));
                    //rg.addView(rb);

                }
            }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(con, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, radioadapt);

            spinnerrg.setAdapter(adapter);
            TextView radioText = new TextView(con);
            radioText.setText(child.getAttribute("label"));
            //spinnerrg.setTag(child.getAttribute("id"));
            contList.add(radioText);
            contList.add(spinnerrg);
```